# MySQL: Updating records across a parent/ child tables, skipping unique key conflicts on either the parent OR child table, without using a cursor

Tags: mysql, sql-update

This is my first question! Hopefully I haven't done too much wrong ... but if I have, feel free to let me know - advice is what I came here for. :)

I'd like to update a group of records in MySQL, but only if all the records meet a certain criteria. If possible, I'd like to do this without using a cursor.

### The Situation:

I have two tables, a parent and a child, called the "DriverHeader" and "DriverDetail" tables, respectively. For legacy reasons, each DriverHeader and DriverDetail record belongs to a carrier. The tables have uniqueness constraints on the Carrier_No - (Driver_No/CardNumber) combinations, so I can't make duplicates.

I'd like to transfer my data between carriers, but only if I can move both the parent AND its children. If any of the records in the group throw a uniqueness error, I want to abort the move.

I have two simple examples of the problem below, but my **ultimate** goal is to be able to do this with multiple drivers to move, with only one SQL query, and no cursor.

#### Example 1:

DriverHeader Table:

```
| id | Driver_No | Carrier_No |
|----|-----------|------------|
| 1  | 01        | 123        |
| 2  | 45        | 456        |
```

DriverDetail Table:

```
| DriverHeader_id | CardNumber | Carrier_No |
|-----------------|------------|------------|
| 1               | 001        | 123        |
| 1               | 002        | 123        |
| 2               | 345        | 456        |
```

I'd like to move driver '01' to carrier '456'. In this case, this is fine.

#### Example 2:

DriverHeader Table:

```
| id | Driver_No | Carrier_No |
|----|-----------|------------|
| 1  | 01        | 123        |
| 2  | 45        | 456        |
```

DriverDetail Table:

```
| DriverHeader_id | CardNumber | Carrier_No |
|-----------------|------------|------------|
| 1               | 001        | 123        |
| 1               | 002        | 123        |
| 2               | 002        | 456        |
```

Now when I try to move driver 01 to carrier 456, I shouldn't be able to, because Carrier 456 is already using one of the card numbers assigned to that driver, card 002.

### My work so far:

I have a procedure, TransferDriversToCarrier, that moves the records, but it currently uses a cursor to go through the DriverHeader table, which I don't like. I'm using transactions to allow me to skip the duplicated records.

```
-- PROCEDURE `MassTransferToCarrier_SimpleDriver`(IN `InCarrierNoFrom` CHAR(3), IN `InCarrierNoTo` CHAR(3))
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE uniqueKeyFail INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE DriverHeaderId INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE DriverDetailUpdateCount INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE DriverHeaderUpdateCount INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE myCursor_DriverRecord CURSOR FOR SELECT dh.id FROM DriverHeader dh WHERE dh.Carrier_No = InCarrierNoFrom;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' SET uniqueKeyFail = TRUE;

    OPEN myCursor_DriverRecord;

       read_loop_driver: LOOP

        START TRANSACTION;

            SET uniqueKeyFail = FALSE;

                FETCH myCursor_DriverRecord INTO DriverHeaderId;

                IF done THEN
                    LEAVE read_loop_driver;
                END IF;

                UPDATE test.DriverDetail
                SET Carrier_No = InCarrierNoTo
                WHERE DriverHeader_id = DriverHeaderId
                ;

                IF uniqueKeyFail THEN
                    ITERATE read_loop_driver;
                END IF;

                SELECT
                ROW_COUNT() + DriverDetailUpdateCount INTO DriverDetailUpdateCount;

                UPDATE test.DriverHeader
                SET Carrier_No = InCarrierNoTo
                WHERE id = DriverHeaderId
                ;

                IF uniqueKeyFail THEN
                    ITERATE read_loop_driver;
                END IF;

                SELECT
                ROW_COUNT() + DriverHeaderUpdateCount INTO DriverHeaderUpdateCount;

            COMMIT;

       END LOOP;

    CLOSE myCursor_DriverRecord;

END
```

The most important part of this setup is that it aborts my move on the current header/ detail group if it encounters a uniqueness error during any of the records in the header-detail set, but it still goes through all the header records I have under my "From" carrier. Here's another example, which hopefully clarifies what happens:

```
SELECT * FROM DriverHeader dh JOIN DriverDetail dd ON dh.id = dd.DriverHeader_id;

    | id | Driver_No | Carrier_No | DriverHeader_id | CardNumber | Carrier_No |
    |----|-----------|------------|-----------------|------------|------------|
    | 1  | 01        | 123        | 1               | 001        | 123        |
    | 2  | 45        | 456        | 1               | 002        | 123        |
    | 1  | 01        | 123        | 2               | 002        | 456        |
    | 3  | 02        | 123        | 3               | 003        | 123        |

CALL TransferDriversToCarrier('123','456');

SELECT * FROM DriverHeader dh JOIN DriverDetail dd ON dh.id = dd.DriverHeader_id;

    | id | Driver_No | Carrier_No | DriverHeader_id | CardNumber | Carrier_No |
    |----|-----------|------------|-----------------|------------|------------|
    | 1  | 01        | 123        | 1               | 001        | 123        |
    | 2  | 45        | 456        | 1               | 002        | 123        |
    | 1  | 01        | 123        | 2               | 002        | 456        |
    | 3  | 02        | 456        | 3               | 003        | 456        |
```

However, all the research I've done on SQL says cursors are a last resort, and I've also noticed that they're slow on moderately large (order 100k records) tables. So, I'd like to accomplish this same move in a single UPDATE statement, without using a cursor. Do you know how to do this with MySQL?

Thank you in advance for any tips!

Comment: Try to rewrite it without a `cursor`.  SQL is a 'set' language, it does not work nearly as well when writing things procedurally.

Comment: @RickJames thanks so much for the response!

Unfortunately, I'm actually a little stumped on __how__ to write this without the cursor, and still watch for unique key violations on both tables ... that's actually what I meant to ask in this question! 

I'll keep thinking about a solution myself, but since I have you, do you have tips on rewriting this?